# Getting jQuery.data functionality without jQuery

Tags: javascript

You can quite easily set a data attribute of any element with jquery using `$('#elid').data('key', value)`. You can do the same using `document.querySelector('#elid').setAttribute('data-key', value)`

However, jQuery gives you a special ability that querySelector doesn't - the ability to add attributes of an arbitrary type (including functions, and I think promises, which is what I need).

So if you were to do `$('#elid').data('key', function(){console.log('yes')})` with jQuery, and then `$('#elid').data('key')()`, it would log 'yes' to the console -- we can just assign a function to the element as a data attribute and run it whenever.

But we can't do the same with 'setAttribute' -- when we do it, it apparently just assigns a stringified form of the function to the data attribute, rather than the actual function.

I've provided example code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8e1wyL41/

So how can I apply data to elements with plain javascript, just like jQuery, including the ability to have arbitrary functions or javascript objects as data attribute values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery#data()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/data.js#L96) uses an [internal object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/data/Data.js) to keep track of data values. It does not update the element to have new or changed data-* attributes when setting data values. When retrieving a data value, if the internal object does not have a set value it will attempt to get it from the data-* attributes.

A overly simplified way of doing this without jQuery would be to just use an object and store your data on that

```
var element = document.querySelector("div");
element.customData = {};
//get data example, check if customData has a value first, if not use dataset
var someData = element.customData["somedata"] || element.dataset["somedata"];
//set
element.customData["somedata"] = function(){};
```

If you don't want to contaminate the element with arbitrary properties you could use a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), pending on browser support, to associate a data object with the element. This also allows for using a single object to maintain other element data objects as well. The key to the data object is the element object itself. And the data object will get deleted from the map automatically once the element is garbage collected

```
var dataMap = new WeakMap();
var element = document.querySelector('div');
var elementData = dataMap.get(element);

if(!elementData){
   dataMap.set(element, elementData = {});
}
//get data example, check if data object has a value first, if not use dataset
var someData = elementData["somedata"] || element.dataset["somedata"];
//set
elementData["somedata"] = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.dataset` sets or gets a `DOMString` of HTML `data-*`, though you can use `Function()` to call the function stored as string at `HTMLElement.dataset`

```js
document.documentElement.dataset.fn = function fn(...args) {console.log(args)};

new Function("return " + document.documentElement.dataset.fn)()("yes");
```

Comment: I think storing it as a string will ruin the function in my use case, as I may want the function I'm attaching to include closured variables.

Comment: @TKoL _"I think storing it as a string will ruin the function in my use case, as I may want the function I'm attaching to include closured variables."_ Not sure what you mean? You can use `.call()` or `.apply()` to set the context of the called function to the same scope of the variables. Can  you demonstrate how using a string representation of a function would "ruin" the function? You can define an arbitrary property to the element instance, though that is not the same as using `HTMLElement.dataset`, which appears to be the gist of the Question.

Comment: If you want to set an arbitrary property at an `HTMLElement` you can set an object at the element `document.documentElement.data = {}; document.documentElement.data.fn = function(...args){console.log(args)}`, which is different from setting the `data-*` attribute or corresponding `.dataset` property of an element.

Comment: When you say `document.documentElement.data = {};`, is this a normal, documented HTML api, or is this just like adding any random property to any object?

Comment: @TKoL The latter. `HTMLElement.dataset` is part of the HTML [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-dataset)

Comment: for the record, [this is what i mean by stringified functions ruining closures](https://jsfiddle.net/8e1wyL41/1/)

Comment: @TKoL You can set the value using `.dataset` as well and use `Function.prototype.call()` `element.dataset.extraText = extraText;
  let fn = function(){return 'this is the text returned from the plain js function' + this.dataset.extraText};
  element.dataset.fn = fn;var result = new Function("return " + element.dataset.fn)().call(element);` https://jsfiddle.net/8e1wyL41/3/

Comment: That still seems like a terribly limited solution. A lot of extra code just to add more strings, I still can't even reference anything else, like an actual object or a promise or anything.

Comment: @TKoL What are you actually trying to achieve? If you are trying to not use jQuery why compare the implementation of `.dataset` to `jQuery.fn.data()`? If you want to define a custom object at the element you can define that object at the element `document.documentElement.data = {};`. Otherwise, the answer to the question is no, `HTMLElement.dataset` is not the same as `jQuery.fn.data()`

Comment: I asked an open-ended question about how to set and retrieve custom data (including functions and objects) to an element on the dom. I'm not stuck on `.dataset`. I'm incredibly happy to abandon `.dataset` if some other api does what I want. Apparently there's no native API that does what $.data does, and that's a fine answer. Apparently my only option is to just add new properties onto the elements. That's fine. It's not ideal, but it's fine.

Comment: That is not your only option; you could alternatively use Web Components to define custom elements altogether. Why do the properties need to be attached to the `DOM` element?

Comment: I wanted to implement some custom animation functions, and the whole system would require knowing what animations are already applies to certain elements so that I can either wait for them to finish or cancel them and start new ones.